# Finding the Minimum And Maximum in ArrayList w/o Sorting - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, program-entry-point, minimum

I am trying to find the Minimum and Maximum Value in an ArrayList without Sorting:

Here is my Current Attempt - However I cannot seem to be getting it to work properly:

```
import java.util.*;

class Untitled {
    static ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(populateArray(al));
        System.out.println(findMin(al,0));

    }   

    public static ArrayList<Integer> populateArray(ArrayList<Integer> a) {

        al.add(1);
        al.add(2);
        al.add(30);
        al.add(3);
        al.add(13);
        al.add(34);
        al.add(4);
        al.add(3);
        al.add(2);
        al.add(1);
        al.add(93);
        return a;
    }

    public static int findMin(ArrayList<Integer> a, int start) {
        int min = start;

        for(int i=start; i<a.size(); i++) {
            if(a.get(i) < a.get(min)) {
                min = i;
            }
        }
        return start;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're returning `start` at the end.

Comment: Could you share with the potential answerers what problems have you found yet?

Comment: It means you don't want to use `Collections.min` and `Collections.max`. But why?

Comment: return `min` instead of `start` , you don't update `start`

Comment: @Kayaman - I am going to flag your *comment*. That's an *answer*. :P

Comment: @akhil_mittal - Yes, I don't to use them because I'm trying to do it manually

Comment: @TheLostMind I always get those two mixed up :)

Comment: I believe you meant finding `min` and `max` without using standard sorting methods. Do you mean finding them without using sorting at all?

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 8 you can do this very easily traversing the list only once:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = al.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).summaryStatistics();
System.out.println("Minimum is: "+stats.getMin());
System.out.println("Maximum is: "+stats.getMax());
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for something like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findMinMax(new int[] {10,40,50,20,69,37});
    }
    public static void findMinMax(int[] array) {
        if (array == null || array.length < 1)
            return;
        int min = array[0];
        int max = array[0];

        for (int i = 1; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (max < array[i]) {
                max = array[i];
            }

            if (min > array[i]) {
                min = array[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("min: " + min + "\nmax: " + max);
    }
```

Obviously this is not going to one of the most optimized solution but it will work for you. It uses simple comparison to track `min` and `max` values. Output is:

`min: 10
 max: 69`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following::

```
   public static int findMin(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
            int min = 0;

            for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++) {
               if(i==0) min= a.get(i);
                if(a.get(i) < min) {
                    min = a.get(i);
                }
            }
            return min;
        } 

public static int findMax(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
        int max = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++) {
           if(i==0) max= a.get(i);               
           if(a.get(i) > max) {
                max = a.get(i);
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```